# Parse data cleanup before migration to self hosted server

Tags: java, parse-platform

Hi I want to clean my Parse tables before migration. The issue is I have tables having a pointer to User table but the relevant user has been already deleted.
So I want a function that would help me delete this data

Thanks in advance

Comment: This shouldn't be possible...when you delete a user, parse automatically deletes all pointers to that user....

Comment: This doesn't happen in my case, I have data in other tables having pointer to User but there doesn't exists the same user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I m not able to find out any default method for this 
i have written some code for this in java 
may be helpful to you

```
public void DataCleanUp()
{
    Log.d("TaDeleted","inside");
    String[] tableCloumn={"User Pointer Column Names",""};
    String[] tableArray={"Class Names Here ",""};



        for(int i=0;i<tableArray.length;i++)
        {
            List<ParseObject> objects=null;
            ParseQuery query=new ParseQuery(tableArray[i]);
            query.setLimit(1000);
            query.include(tableCloumn[i]);
            try {
                objects= query.find();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(objects!=null)
                if(!objects.isEmpty())
                {
                    Log.d("Table To Deleted",""+tableArray[i]);
                    for(int j=0;j<objects.size();j++)
                    {
                        if((ParseUser) objects.get(j).get(tableCloumn[i])==null)
                        {
                            try {
                                objects.get(j).delete();
                                Log.d("Deleted", "" + objects.get(j).getObjectId());
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

another method  may helpful

public void DataCleanUp(String userId)
    {
        Log.d("TaDeleted","inside");
        String[] tableCloumn={"User Pointer 1","User Pointer 2"..};
        String[] tableArray={"Parse class Names 1","Parse class Names 2"...};

```
    List<ParseUser> user=null;
    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query1 = ParseUser.getQuery();
    query1.whereEqualTo("objectId", userId);
    try {
          user=query1.find();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(user!=null)
    for(int i=0;i<tableArray.length;i++)
    {
        List<ParseObject> objects=null;
        ParseQuery query=new ParseQuery(tableArray[i]);
        //query.whereEqualTo(tableCloumn[i], user.get(0));
        query.whereEqualTo(tableCloumn[i], user.get(0));
        query.setLimit(1000);
        try {
            objects= query.find();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            if(objects!=null)
                if(!objects.isEmpty())
                {
                    Log.d("Table To Deleted",""+tableArray[i]);
                    for(int j=0;j<objects.size();j++)
                    {
                        try {
                            Log.d("Deleted",""+objects.get(j).getObjectId());
                            objects.get(j).delete();
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
    }
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```